# Placing image in a view

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am struggling with the layout in a view. I am trying to place the random picture(in this case starbucks logo) to the left of the blue view. I would like it to be aligned with left border. No matter what layout properties i use for it, it doesn't work as i would expect.

```
logoStyle:{
    width: 210,
    height: 120,
    left: 0,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',

  },
```

[Here is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdmFe.png)

Answer (score 0):

You want put image logo on the left of background view. Here's example:

```
      render() {
             <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', 
                   alignItems: 'flex-start', justifyContent: 'flex-start'}} >
                   <Image style={{width: 20, height: 20}} />
                 </View>
             </View>
       }
```

You can try it!

Cheer!

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply! I did it the way you suggested  but still it doesn't move logo to the left. I put the logo in the view with flex property and apply the style.

Comment: logoStyle:{
    width: 210,
    height: 120,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    flexDirection: 'row', 
    alignItems: 'flex-start', 
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
}